# NullPointerException ao ler JSONArray passando String

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception

Esse é o meu código, que recebe um String em formato JSON da url https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados

Ao extrair os dados, conforme essa classe/método
public class JSONDataHandler {

```
public List<String> extractDados(String string) {
    List<String> dados = new ArrayList<>();
    try {


        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(string);
        JSONObject estado;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            estado = new JSONObject(jsonArray.getString(i));
            dados.add(estado.get("sigla").toString());
        }
        return dados;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

recebo a mensagem de erro:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] not a string.
    at org.json.JSONArray.getString(JSONArray.java:329)
    at utils.JSONDataHandler.extractDados(JSONDataHandler.java:20)
    at main.Main.gerarEstado(Main.java:40)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:21)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Porém esse mesmo método (com as outras classes HTTPREsponse e HTTPCall [que tratam de obter a string do site]) são utilizadas num projeto android e funcionam perfeitamente. Porém ao tentar aplicar num projeto java, não consigo resultados.

Ao rodar em modo debug, vejo que o erro está na linha

```
estado = new JSONObject(jsonArray.getString(i));
```

mas não consigo compreender porque está acontecendo esse nullpointer

Classe/Metodo main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder construtorString = new StringBuilder();

    List<String> estadosArray = gerarEstado();

    for (String estado : estadosArray) {
        System.out.println(estado);
        construtorString.append(estado).append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

}

private static List<String> gerarEstado() {
    HTTPCall estadoHTTP = new HTTPCall(URL_ESTADOS);
    String respondeStr = null;
    try {
        HTTPResponse response = estadoHTTP.execute(HTTPCall.Method.GET);
        respondeStr = response.extractDataAsString();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Logger.getLogger(Level.SEVERE + " " + Main.class.getName() + " " + ioe);
    }

    return new JSONDataHandler().extractDados(respondeStr);
}
```

Comment: Eu coloquei logo no início da pergunta a URL que devolve o JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro do `JSONArray`, você tem uma coleção de `JSONObject` e não `String` (por isso a mensagem `JSONArray[0] not a string.`). A `NullPointerException` acontece porque você tenta acessar `estado` que ainda está nulo por causa do erro anterior.

A maneira correta é primeiro acessar o `JSONObject` e depois procurar a chave:

```
List<String> dados = new ArrayList<>();
try {
  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(string);
  JSONObject estado;
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     estado = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     dados.add(estado.getString("sigla"));
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

No entanto, você consegue fazer de modo mais compacto, sem a necessidade de declarar a variável `estado`:

```
//...
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(string);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     dados.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sigla"));
}
//...
```

Usando Java 8, fica mais compacto ainda:

```
List<String> dados = new ArrayList<>();
try {
  new JsonArray(string).forEach(estado -> dados.add(((JSONObject) estado).getString("sigla")));
} catch (JsonException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Se imprimirmos `dados` em quaisquer das soluções, teremos:

```
//RO AC AM RR PA AP TO MA PI CE RN PB PE AL SE BA MG ES RJ SP PR SC RS MS MT GO DF
```

Comment: Huum, show de bola. Entendi agora pq tava errando. Muito obrigado.